# String Concatenation to Call A Custom Variable

Tags: go, hugo

```
{{ $var := "$" + "foobar" }}
{{ range $var }}
```

I want this line of code to be the same as

```
{{ range $foobar }}
```

I tried using the printf command but it doesn't seem to work

```
{{ $var := printf "$" "foobar"}}
{{ range $var }}
```

Can anyone help lead me in the right direction? Thank you !

Comment: It is not possible to reference a template variable using a string.  Describe the higher-level problem that you are trying to solve. There may be a good solution to that problem.

Comment: I have some variables that I want to range through, nested in another range function. So I want the first time through the range loop to call on variable 1, the 2nd time to call on variable 2, etc. Can I make a list of variables and then use a range loop with a counter and then call reference the variables using the list index some how?

Comment: Create a [template function](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template#Template.Funcs) that returns its variadic arguments as a slice: `func(v ...interface{}) interface{} { return v }` ).  Create a slice of the values:  `{{$x := makeSlice $var1 $var2 $var3 }}`.   Range over $x.